# Spark custom log4j integration for Scala application

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, log4j, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to spark and Scala as well,
Question is I am not able to debug my application.

I have developed a spark application using Maven in Scala.
But I am not able to log the details, meaning not getting where that log file is getting generated, cause as per log4j property, log file is not available at given path.

Any specific changes I need to do, to get that log file.

I am testing my application in Hortonworks.

Command for submitting the app:

```
bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class com.examples.MainExample lib/Test.jar
```

log4j.properties file is kept at src/resources folder

PFB log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/spark.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n


# By default, everything goes to console and file
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, myConsoleAppender, RollingAppender

 # The noisier spark logs go to file only
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivty.spark.MapOutputTracker=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to solve this issue via application but, in if you change log4j.properties in conf folder as below, it will write logs to give file.
Make sure the path has write access.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/sparkLog/SparkOut.log

log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the log4j.properties inside 'src/main/scala/resources'.